# T-SQL get value from XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery-sql

I am trying to query XML (SSRS) in SQL Server; I want to get the value from the TO in this case.

```
<ParameterValues>
    <ParameterValue>
        <Name>TO</Name>
        <Value>PacoAT@Stack.com</Value>
    </ParameterValue>
    <ParameterValue>
        <Name>RenderFormat</Name>
        <Value>EXCEL</Value>
    </ParameterValue>
</ParameterValues>
```

I have tried a few queries but cant seem to get to that level.

Comment: *"I have tried a few queries"* and what were those attempts? Why didn't they work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using XQuery

```sql
SELECT
  [TO] = t.XmlColumn.value('(ParameterValues/ParameterValue[Name/text() = "TO"]/Value/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM YourTable t
```

`/` is a child node navigation. `[]` is a predicate test on a particular node. So this looks for `ParameterValues/ParameterValue` which has a `Name` child with text `TO` and returns the `Value` child's text.

Note the use of `text()` rather than relying on implicit conversion/atomization. Also `.value` needs to be guaranteed a single result, so needs `[1]`

Comment: Thanks. I  Spent way too much time on that :)